# changing .then code to async/await gives unhandled rejection error in react js code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react JS and this is the code of tutorial person's code where they used .then but I tried doing it with async await, and I'm getting slightly different result than the tutorial person, below is tut person's code

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => {
      if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status <= 299) {
        return resp.json();
      } else {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setIsError(true);
        throw new Error(resp.statusText);
      }
    })
    .then((user) => {
      const { login } = user;
      setUser(login);
      setIsLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}, []);
```

my code:

```
const getusers = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status <= 299) {
    const user = await resp.json();
    const { login } = user;
    setuser(login);
    setIsLoading(false);
  } else {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setIsError(true);
    throw new Error(resp.statusText);
  }
};
try {
  useEffect(() => {
    await getusers();
  }, []);
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error");
}
```

This is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP2eX.jpg). The tutorial person doesn't get the error screen at the end(it should only show error as text)

Comment: You need to put that `try..catch` inside `useEffect(() => { try { ...`. As it is you are trying UseEffect's call which is returned immediately without executing `getusers()` so the try..catch does not catch anything. The callback you passed to `useEffect` executes in a different context so it needs its own try...catch

Comment: In the top code you haae `setUser` in the bottom one `setuser`.

Comment: Also `useEffect(() => { await getusers(); }, []);` cannot work because the callback given to `useEffect` is not `async` but you use `await` in it. And if it was `async` you need the `try`/`catch` inside it as slebetman said.

Comment: @VLAZ thats 2 different codes one is mine and another is tutorial person's. i forgot to delete the await

Comment: @slebetman I tried          `     useEffect(() => {
        try{
          getusers();
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log('error')
          }
      },[]); `        but still got the same error

Comment: `useEffect(() => { try{ getusers(); } catch(error){ console.log('error') } },[]);`  is not correct because `getusers` is async, so you need to `await` it in order to handle the promise: `useEffect(async () => { try{ await getusers(); } catch(error){ console.log('error') } },[]);`

Comment: …or use `useEffect(() => { getusers().catch(error => { console.log('error') }); },[]);`

Comment: If that is literally what you did I think you forgot `await`

Comment: Also, in your original code posted above you forgot `async` -- `useEffect(async () => ...`

Comment: @slebetman the async didnt work inside the useffect when i had tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem it was with try catch I moved try catch to inside the getuser function. It works now.

```
const getusers = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status <= 299) {
try{
    const user = await resp.json();
    const { login } = user;
    setuser(login);
    setIsLoading(false);
  } else {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setIsError(true);
    throw new Error(resp.statusText);
  }}
catch(error){
console.log("error");
}
};
  useEffect(() => {
    getusers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to define the promise within the useEffect hook like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let didCancel = false;

  const getUsers = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(url);

    if (didCancel) { // Ignore if we started fetching something else
      console.log(resp);
      return;
    }

    if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status <= 299) {
      const user = await resp.json();
      const { login } = user;
      setuser(login);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } else {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setIsError(true);
      throw new Error(resp.statusText);
    }
  };

  getUsers();
  return () => { didCancel = true; }; // Remember if we start fetching something else
}, []);
```

note: if your promise depends on any values, like a userId string or something, then it need to go into the dependency array at the end of the useEffect hook.

Here are some good reference that addresses this issue:

[react-hooks-fetch-data](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data)

[github issue on same topic](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326)

Comment: I tried what you said, but it still had same result.  Also, it works after i removed the throw statement but i dont notice difference with or without throw

Comment: you might have to set an error state and have your component handle that, rather than throwing an error in your promise. So in your else statement, just have a setError(true) or setError(error message) and then display that in the ui somehow.

throwing an error will resolve the promise resulting in your hook ending without any side effects.

Comment: I got the problem it was with try catch I moved try catch to inside the getuser function. It works now